# Mapinfo and qgis file's datum problem

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapinfo, datum, tab

please refer to following link for the explanation of the problem I had.

do you have any idea on this?

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Mapinfo-and-qgis-file-s-datum-problem-td5091891.html#a5100434

Comment: The lenght of a degree depends on your latitude check this out:http://www.csgnetwork.com/degreelenllavcalc.html

Comment: Please post your actual question here: we do not answer questions posted on other sites.

Comment: Well, at least 2 of "we" have managed to answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @UffeKousgaard and Jimenez , This sounds right I will try it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @whuber sorry for that, I am really really new be in stackexchange, I dont even know how to accept a question. My question was really simple, mapinfo or qgis fails to respond my needs, there is some incosistency between them. I asked if anyone have have an ide. Thanks for your response though...

Comment: @Uffe That's beside the point.  SE aims to build *good* questions and *good* answers.  This one is likely to vanish and become incomprehensible due to future link rot, leaving us with junk that gets in the way of the usefulness of our site to future participants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you get closer to the poles, those x degrees are no longer 100 meters in both North/South and East/West direction. I guess MapInfo is correct here, since it allows you to specify 100 meters, while QGIS wants degrees or you will have to go through a reprojection to UTM, do the buffering and then reproject back again.